# Do City of Mist characters need to have a specific legend associated with them?

Tags: city-of-mist

The book talks about having a Mythos surround your character like Thor, the Chupacabra, or even Puss in Boots. However a lot of the sample characters in the starter like Flicker or Mitosis don't have as obvious of a Mythos origins and feel more like traditional superheroes. My question really is can you just make a character who has superpowers via a mythos, or is there an expectation that you always define a legend around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the *City of Mist* setting, your mythos is explicitly rooted in a story**:

> In *City of Mist*, you take the role of an ordinary modern-day individual in whom an ancient myth, a legend, or a story has awakened. (Player's Guide, pg. 42) …
>
> There are only three things that can be said about the Mythoi for certain: they are a source of unimaginable power, they are mysterious beyond fathom, and they always want to tell their story, whispering it from beyond the veil of Mist we mortals cannot see. (Player's Guide, pg. 23)

**— but you don't have to take that *super* literally.**

The important thing here isn't so much a reference to a specific character (like "Captain Hook") as a kind of narrative momentum — your mythos introduces deep mysteries into your life and pulls you towards some kind of destiny.

A fictional trope like "science zombie" (Post Mortem) can provide all that. Funny enough, so could picking a superhero archetype your character embodies. Or your story could be something ancient and primeval, some scrap of a legend in collective memory long ago scrubbed of its specifics. The important thing is to remember that these aren't neutral descriptions of a "power set," they're a supernatural force driving you towards something, and you'll likely discover the details of how and why — and your own group's answers to the setting's build-in mysteries — in play.

That means, for example, that Mitosis' transformation isn't just a done deal that explains his abilities, backstory, and the personal challenges he faces in his life. It's an enduring **force** in some way. The experience of transformation itself is a part of him. (Even if his relationship with it starts out as simple as "Why did this happen to me?" and "How can I reverse my transformation?" — remember, the characters likely start out knowing less about how their world works than you, the players, do!)

---

**Rules-wise? The game works fine in a modified setting that doesn't associate mythoi with stories at all.** I've dabbled with using CoM to play "occult awakening" fiction in the style of *Mage* and *Kult* (some of the terminology is even the same), using the rules *entirely as-is*. It's worked great so far!

You could also attempt more conventional superhero-noir in the style of *Jessica Jones*, but without a "Mists"-like force at play, the relationship between Logos and Mythos (as represented in the mechanics) isn't quite as powerful; you may need to hack the character development rules a bit to get something that better fits your campaigns' core theme.

Answer (score 1):

I only have the starter set.  The full book presumably explains it in more depth.  (It's certainly thick enough.)

The major statements in the starter set about your relationship with the Mythos are:

> The protagonists are Gateways, ordinary people who became the living embodiment of a legend, their Mythos.

...

> you’re also a gateway to a strange legendary force: a Mythos.

Each Mythos theme also has a mystery associated with it, and there are specific rules about exploring those mysteries. It looks to me that developing your relationship and understanding of the Mythos is meant to be a major part of the game.

So, I certainly don't think the game expects you to associate your character with a specific legend when you create it.  I also don't think there's any indication that you ultimately need to define the Mythos that specifically as you explore it.

The starter set doesn't mention the specific examples from your question (Thor, etc.). To me, these seem like they would be examples of how a Mythos has manifested in the world previously, not examples of what the Mythos itself is.

There seems to be room to make the Mythos as vague or specific as you like.  I imagine different games might have guidelines for this.  A particular campaign might expect you to have a Mythos tied to a specific ancient deity, but I don't think the game itself requires that.

Comment: Could it be that PCs are different? That is, protagonists (i.e. PCs) are Gateways and everybody else just isn't? Or does the game not make that kind of PC/NPC divide?

Comment: It definitely implies that NPCs *can* be Gateways (the sample Danger in the starter set is an NPC that has Mythos themes).  It's not clear to me how that relates to the original question.

Comment: (The question says, "However a lot of the sample characters in the starter like Flicker or Mitosis don't have as obvious of a Mythos origins and feel more like traditional superheroes." If these sample characters were intended to be NPCs and not protagonists, then these sample characters need not be Gateways. Anyway, I was just exploring an avenue. I'll delete my comments shortly.)

Comment: I see.  The sample characters seem to me to be intended to be PCs (they are presented as "playbooks" with a "how to play" section on each).  Although you could certainly use them as NPCs as well.  I don't think you should delete your comments, I just wasn't clear what the connection was.